# How can I split a string into substrings by parentheses, but also getting the ones inside others?

Tags: string, algorithm, substring, calculator, parentheses

I'm trying to code a calculator and i'm trying to create a "Suboperation" class.
I want to generate smaller suboperations from a big input. For example:
(4+5) is a suboperation made of ParamA (4) ParamB (5) and Operator(+).
The problem is, that i want to make it so (4+(6+5)) is a suboperation inside another.

I guess it will give me problems in due time, but i cannot get over the input recognition part yet.

I managed to make it get this string "(4+5)/(6-8)" and separate it between (4+5) and (6-8).
The problem lies when i try to get...
This: ((4+5)-7)

Into THIS: (4+5), (4+5)-7.

I've tried to save the opening parentheses and closing parentheses indexes on different arrays,
to then figure out a pattern to get the substrings, but i'm stuck.

Something like this:

public ArrayList findOperations() {

```
    ArrayList<String> operations = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> start = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> end = new ArrayList();

    int index = 0;

    for (char c : this.input.toCharArray()) {

        if (Character.toString(c).equals("(")) {
            start.add(index);
        }

        if (Character.toString(c).equals(")")) {
            end.add(index);
        }

    }


    int indexNow=0;

    for(int st:start){

      if(start.get(indexNow++)>end.get(indexNow)){
                operations.add(input.substring(st,end.get(indexNow)));
            }
      else{
          break;
      }


      indexNow++;
    }




    return operations;
}
```

CLARIFICATION:
I want a method that gets and input like this:
"((4+5)-6)"
And returns an array of strings like this:
["(4+5)-6", "4+5"]

Any ideas ? This is the first time since i've started learning where i feel like I need some serious help. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: i find it not easy to understand from the explanation/example what you are trying to achieve

Comment: CLARIFICATION: I want a method that gets and input like this: "((4+5)-6)" And returns an array of strings like this: ["(4+5)-6", "4+5"]

Comment: Hint: dealing with parentheses is a lot easier using recursive functions than strictly using iterative loops.

Comment: Agreed with stef. Try some recursion exercises and then revisit this problem. Probably you took a problem tougher that you can solve yourself right now.

Comment: I'm not quite there with a proper answer, so just an idea: go "inside out" instead?

Comment: Ty for those answers, i really enjoy the idea of a recursive function, gonna try to do some work with that, because even if I manage to code a function that does what i need, it would be rendered useless the moment i add even more parentheses !

Comment: Build a tree and you don't need any parantheses at all. All the leaves will be numbers and all inner nodes operators.